# простенькая админка на php

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь разобраться как сделать простенькую админку на php.
Кое-как собрал регистрацию и логин чтобы писала и сверяла с базой. Но совсем запутался с тем как правильно сделать логику сессионной переменной для скажем пользователей с разными привилегиями.

Буду благодарен за простой пример реализации логики. В инете не могу найти ничего толкового по этой теме.

Ну так чтоб пример был на старом чистом php без ооп и фреймворков. Цель - разобраться как работает.

Comment: Какое отношение привилегии имеют к сессионной переменной? Суть вопроса непонятна. Да и вообще о каких привилегиях речь и какая сессионная переменная имеется в виду?

Comment: Ну привелигии имею ввиду пользователи будут разные и разное отображения для них.
Переменная - $abc = $_SESSION['connect'] например ну из сессионного массива.

Comment: И в чём собственно суть проблемы? `if (привилегия_есть) { отобразить_одно(); } else { отобразить_другое(); }`

Comment: В БД добавить столбец привилегий. При входе в систему и проверке пароля - получать привилегию пользователя. Помещать ещё в сессию. $_SESSION['privilege']. Дальше в своём проекте использовать то, что Вам написал andreymal - если есть привилегия, то показывать некоторые поля, если нет, то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно написали в комментариях, дополню лишь небольшими примерами.
Вот так может выглядеть таблица с привилегиями (или ролями):

```
user_id | privilege
   1    |    1
  134   |    7
```

То есть юзер с id=1 имеет высшим уровнем доступа, так как мы решили, что чем меньше число, тем круче будет юзер.

Или так, если использовать названия действий:

```
user_id |   role
   1    | show_news
   1    | edit_news
   1    | remove_news
  134   | show_news
```

Мы даём юзеру с id=1 права на просмотр, редактирование и удаление новостей, а юзеру id=134 только на просмотр.

Далее, у вас появится функция на получения ID юзера, который делает запрос к серверу:

```
function getUserId() {
    //тут всё зависит от того, что именно вы будете хранить в $_SESSION по юзеру
    //если сразу ID, то будет так
    return $_SESSION['user'];
}
```

У вас появится функция проверки роли или привилегии пользователя, что-то вроде этого:

```
//$role - число, обозначающее уровень доступа (от 1 до 10, например)
//или название действия ("show_news", "edit_news", "remove_news" например)
function canUserDoIt($role) { 
    $user_id = getUserId();
    //Запрос к бд, который достаёт нужную инфу из таблицы с привилегиями
    "SELECT id FROM наша_таблица WHERE $user_id = user_id AND $role = role"
    if (такая запись есть) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```